# Which brain regions are D1 dopamine receptors expressed, and which brain regions are D2 dopamine receptors expressed?

Tags: neuroscience, endocrinology

This is a follow-up question to [If D1 receptors stimulate adenylate cyclase (through GPCRs) and D2 receptors inhibit it, then why do mutations in both have similar effects?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/730/if-d1-receptors-stimulate-adenylate-cyclase-through-gpcrs-and-d2-receptors-inh).

As a further question - I'd like to ask: do D1 dopamine receptors have the same (excitatory) effect everywhere in the brain? And do D2 dopamine receptors have the same (inhibitory) effect everywhere in the brain?

Answer (score 3):

As to your main question, I imagine the Paul Allan Brain Atlas has what you're looking for. In 3D even.

- [Human Brain Map](http://human.brain-map.org/)
- [D1 Receptor](http://human.brain-map.org/microarray/search/show?exact_match=false&search_term=drd1&search_type=gene)
- [D2 Receptor](http://human.brain-map.org/microarray/search/show?exact_match=false&search_term=drd2&search_type=gene&page_num=0)
- [Also comes in mouse flavored.](http://mouse.brain-map.org/experiment/show/352)

Offhand, I cannot be of assistance for the second question.

Comment: To your second question, from what I remember the activity of each receptor is the same, it is the balance of the frequency of activating and inhibitory receptors that summate temporally and spatially that give the overall effect.